# I want to add an extra amount if the payment method is cash on delivery

Tags: magento-1.9, php, cash-on-delivery, extrafee

I have an E-commerce website where i want the users to pay extra some money if they choose "Cash on delivery" as payment option. Can you please help me achieve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Step 1: Create a file app/etc/modules/Stack_ExtraFee.xml and add the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Stack_ExtraFee>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_SalesRule/>
            </depends>
        </Stack_ExtraFee>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> Step 2: Create a file config.xml under app/code/local/Stack/ExtraFee/etc and add the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Stack_ExtraFee>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </Stack_ExtraFee>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <stack_extrafee>
                <class>Stack_ExtraFee_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>stack_extrafee_resource</resourceModel>
            </stack_extrafee>
            <stack_extrafee_resource>
                <class>Stack_ExtraFee_Model_Resource</class>
            </stack_extrafee_resource>
            <salesrule>
                <rewrite>
                    <validator>Stack_ExtraFee_Model_SalesRule_Discount_Validator</validator>
                </rewrite>
            </salesrule>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <stack_extrafee>
                <class>Stack_ExtraFee_Block</class>
            </stack_extrafee>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <stack_extrafee>
                <class>Stack_ExtraFee_Helper</class>
            </stack_extrafee>
        </helpers>
        <sales>
            <quote>
                <totals>
                    <extra_fee_rule>
                        <class>stack_extrafee/quote_address_total_fee_rule</class>
                        <after>discount</after>
                        <before>grand_total</before>
                    </extra_fee_rule>
                </totals>
            </quote>
            <order_invoice>
                <totals>
                    <extra_fee_rule>
                        <class>stack_extrafee/sales_order_invoice_total_fee_rule</class>
                        <after>discount</after>
                    </extra_fee_rule>
                </totals>
            </order_invoice>
        </sales>
        <pdf>
            <totals>
                <extra_fee_rule>
                    <title>Extra Rule Fee</title>
                    <source_field>extra_fee_rule_amount</source_field>
                    <title_source_field>extra_fee_rule_description</title_source_field>
                    <font_size>7</font_size>
                    <display_zero>0</display_zero>
                    <sort_order>300</sort_order>
                </extra_fee_rule>
            </totals>
        </pdf>
        <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote_address>
                <base_extra_fee_rule_amount>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </base_extra_fee_rule_amount>
                <extra_fee_rule_amount>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </extra_fee_rule_amount>
                <extra_fee_rule_description>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </extra_fee_rule_description>
            </sales_convert_quote_address>
            <sales_convert_order>
                <extra_fee_rule_description>
                    <to_invoice>*</to_invoice>
                </extra_fee_rule_description>
            </sales_convert_order>
        </fieldsets>
        <resources>
            <stack_extrafee_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Stack_ExtraFee</module>
                    <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </stack_extrafee_setup>
        </resources>
        <events>
            <salesrule_rule_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <stack_extrafee>
                        <class>stack_extrafee/observer</class>
                        <method>beforeSaveSalesRuleModel</method>
                    </stack_extrafee>
                </observers>
            </salesrule_rule_save_before>
            <adminhtml_block_salesrule_actions_prepareform>
                <observers>
                    <stack_extrafee_prepare_form>
                        <class>stack_extrafee/observer</class>
                        <method>prepareFormSalesRuleEdit</method>
                    </stack_extrafee_prepare_form>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_block_salesrule_actions_prepareform>
            <paypal_prepare_line_items>
                <observers>
                    <stack_extrafee_paypal_prepare>
                        <class>stack_extrafee/observer</class>
                        <method>paypalPrepareLineItems</method>
                    </stack_extrafee_paypal_prepare>
                </observers>
            </paypal_prepare_line_items>
        </events>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <stack_extrafee>
                    <file>stack_extrafee.xml</file>
                </stack_extrafee>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <stack_extrafee>
                    <file>stack_extrafee.xml</file>
                </stack_extrafee>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <default>
        <extra_fee_settings>
            <extra_fee_rule>
                <active>1</active>
                <label>Extra Fee</label>
            </extra_fee_rule>
        </extra_fee_settings>
    </default>
</config>
```

> Step 3: Add the file app/code/local/Stack/ExtraFee/etc/adminhtml.xml for defining ACL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <extra_fee_settings translate="title">
                                        <title>Extra Fee Settings</title>
                                        <sort_order>55</sort_order>
                                    </extra_fee_settings>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

> Step 4: Add module's system configuration in app/code/local/Stack/ExtraFee/etc/system.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <extra_fee_settings translate="label" module="sales">
            <label>Extra Fee Settings</label>
            <tab>sales</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>304</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <extra_fee_rule translate="label">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Rule Extra Fee</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </active>
                        <label translate="label">
                            <label>Label</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </label>
                    </fields>
                </extra_fee_rule>
            </groups>
        </extra_fee_settings>
    </sections>
</config>
```

> Step 5: Add helper class in app/code/local/Voronoy/Stack/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class Stack_ExtraFee_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    const XML_PATH_EXTRA_FEE_RULE_ACTIVE              = 'extra_fee_settings/extra_fee_rule/active';
    const XML_PATH_EXTRA_FEE_RULE_LABEL               = 'extra_fee_settings/extra_fee_rule/label';

    public function isRuleExtraFeeEnabled()
    {
        $result = (bool) Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EXTRA_FEE_RULE_ACTIVE);
        return $result;
    }

    public function getExtraFeeRuleLabel()
    {
        return (string) Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EXTRA_FEE_RULE_LABEL);
    }
}
```

> Step 6: Add observer class app/code/local/Stack/ExtraFee/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class Stack_ExtraFee_Model_Observer
{
    public function beforeSaveSalesRuleModel($observer)
    {
        if (!Mage::helper('stack_extrafee')->isRuleExtraFeeEnabled()) {
            return $this;
        }
        if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $postData = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
            if (isset($postData['extra_fee_amount'])) {
                $salesRuleModel = $observer->getEvent()->getDataObject();
                $salesRuleModel->setExtraFeeAmount($postData['extra_fee_amount']);
            }
        }
    }

    public function prepareFormSalesRuleEdit($observer)
    {
        if (!Mage::helper('stack_extrafee')->isRuleExtraFeeEnabled()) {
            return $this;
        }
        $model = Mage::registry('current_promo_quote_rule');
        if (!$model) {
            return $this;
        }

        $form = $observer->getEvent()->getForm();
        $fieldset = $form->getElement('action_fieldset');
        $fieldset->addField('extra_fee_amount', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'extra_fee_amount',
            'class' => 'validate-not-negative-number',
            'label' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Extra Fee Amount'),
        ), 'discount_amount');
        $model->setExtraFeeAmount($model->getExtraFeeAmount()*1);
        Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('promo_quote_edit_tab_actions')
            ->setChild('form_after', Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_element_dependence')
            ->addFieldMap('rule_extra_fee_amount', 'extra_fee_amount')
            ->addFieldMap('rule_simple_action', 'simple_action')
            ->addFieldDependence('extra_fee_amount', 'simple_action', array(
                Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::BY_PERCENT_ACTION,
                Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::BY_FIXED_ACTION,
                Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::CART_FIXED_ACTION))
        );
    }

    public function paypalPrepareLineItems($observer)
    {
        /* @var $cart Mage_Paypal_Model_Cart */
        $cart = $observer->getEvent()->getPaypalCart();
        $address = $cart->getSalesEntity()->getIsVirtual() ?
            $cart->getSalesEntity()->getBillingAddress() : $cart->getSalesEntity()->getShippingAddress();
        $feeAmount = $address->getExtraFeeRuleAmount();
        $cart->updateTotal(Mage_Paypal_Model_Cart::TOTAL_TAX, $feeAmount);
    }
}
```

> Step 7: app/code/local/Stack/ExtraFee/Model/SalesRule/Validator.php

```
    <?php
class Stack_ExtraFee_Model_SalesRule_Validator extends Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator
{
    public function process(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract $item)
    {
        $item->setExtraFeeRuleAmount(0);
        $item->setBaseExtraFeeRuleAmount(0);
        $item->setExtraFeeRulePercent(0);
        $quote         = $item->getQuote();
        $address       = $this->_getAddress($item);
        $itemPrice     = $this->_getItemPrice($item);
        $baseItemPrice = $this->_getItemBasePrice($item);
        if ($itemPrice < 0) {
            return $this;
        }
        $appliedRuleIds = array();
        $this->_stopFurtherRules = false;
        foreach ($this->_getRules() as $rule) {
            if (!$this->_isRuleApplicableForItem($rule, $item)) {
                continue;
            }
            $qty                = $this->_getItemQty($item, $rule);
            $extraFeeAmount     = 0;
            $baseExtraFeeAmount = 0;
            switch ($rule->getSimpleAction()) {
                case Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::BY_PERCENT_ACTION:
                    $extraFeePercent = min(100, $rule->getExtraFeeAmount());
                    $step = $rule->getDiscountStep();
                    if ($step) {
                        $qty = floor($qty/$step)*$step;
                    }
                    $_rulePct = $extraFeePercent/100;
                    $extraFeeAmount    = ($qty * $itemPrice - $item->getExtraFeeRuleAmount()) * $_rulePct;
                    $baseExtraFeeAmount = ($qty * $baseItemPrice - $item->getBaseExtraFeeRuleAmount()) * $_rulePct;
                    if (!$rule->getDiscountQty() || $rule->getDiscountQty()>$qty) {
                        $extraFeePercent = min(100, $item->getExtraFeeRulePercent()+$extraFeePercent);
                        $item->setExtraFeeRulePercent($extraFeePercent);
                    }
                    break;
                case Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::BY_FIXED_ACTION:
                    $step = $rule->getDiscountStep();
                    if ($step) {
                        $qty = floor($qty/$step)*$step;
                    }
                    $quoteAmount        = $quote->getStore()->convertPrice($rule->getExtraFeeAmount());
                    $extraFeeAmount     = $qty * $quoteAmount;
                    $baseExtraFeeAmount = $qty * $rule->getExtraFeeAmount();
                    break;
                case Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::CART_FIXED_ACTION:
                    if (empty($this->_rulesItemTotals[$rule->getId()])) {
                        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Item totals are not set for rule.'));
                    }

                    if ($quote->getIsMultiShipping()) {
                        $usedForAddressId = $this->getCartFixedRuleUsedForAddress($rule->getId());
                        if ($usedForAddressId && $usedForAddressId != $address->getId()) {
                            break;
                        } else {
                            $this->setCartFixedRuleUsedForAddress($rule->getId(), $address->getId());
                        }
                    }
                    $cartRules = $address->getCartFixedRules();
                    if (!isset($cartRules[$rule->getId()])) {
                        $cartRules[$rule->getId()] = $rule->getExtraFeeAmount();
                    }
                    if ($cartRules[$rule->getId()] > 0) {
                        if ($this->_rulesItemTotals[$rule->getId()]['items_count'] <= 1) {
                            $quoteAmount = $quote->getStore()->convertPrice($cartRules[$rule->getId()]);
                            $baseExtraFeeAmount= $cartRules[$rule->getId()];
                        } else {
                            $discountRate = $baseItemPrice * $qty /
                                $this->_rulesItemTotals[$rule->getId()]['base_items_price'];
                            $maximumItemDiscount = $rule->getExtraFeeAmount() * $discountRate;
                            $quoteAmount = $quote->getStore()->convertPrice($maximumItemDiscount);
                            $baseExtraFeeAmount = $maximumItemDiscount;
                            $this->_rulesItemTotals[$rule->getId()]['items_count']--;
                        }
                        $extraFeeAmount = $quoteAmount;
                        $extraFeeAmount = $quote->getStore()->roundPrice($extraFeeAmount);
                        $baseExtraFeeAmount = $quote->getStore()->roundPrice($baseExtraFeeAmount);
                        $cartRules[$rule->getId()] -= $baseExtraFeeAmount;
                    }
                    $address->setCartFixedRules($cartRules);
                    break;
            }
            $percentKey = $item->getExtraFeeRulePercent();

            if ($percentKey) {
                $delta      = isset($this->_roundingDeltas[$percentKey]) ? $this->_roundingDeltas[$percentKey] : 0;
                $baseDelta  = isset($this->_baseRoundingDeltas[$percentKey])
                    ? $this->_baseRoundingDeltas[$percentKey]
                    : 0;
                $extraFeeAmount += $delta;
                $baseExtraFeeAmount += $baseDelta;
                $this->_roundingDeltas[$percentKey]     = $extraFeeAmount -
                    $quote->getStore()->roundPrice($extraFeeAmount);
                $this->_baseRoundingDeltas[$percentKey] = $baseExtraFeeAmount -
                    $quote->getStore()->roundPrice($baseExtraFeeAmount);
                $extraFeeAmount = $quote->getStore()->roundPrice($extraFeeAmount);
                $baseExtraFeeAmount = $quote->getStore()->roundPrice($baseExtraFeeAmount);
            } else {
                $extraFeeAmount     = $quote->getStore()->roundPrice($extraFeeAmount);
                $baseExtraFeeAmount = $quote->getStore()->roundPrice($baseExtraFeeAmount);
            }

            $itemExtraFeeRuleAmount = $item->getExtraFeeRuleAmount();
            $itemBaseExtraFeeRuleAmount = $item->getBaseExtraFeeRuleAmount();
            $extraFeeAmount     = $itemExtraFeeRuleAmount + $extraFeeAmount;
            $baseExtraFeeAmount = $itemBaseExtraFeeRuleAmount + $baseExtraFeeAmount;
            $item->setExtraFeeRuleAmount($extraFeeAmount);
            $item->setBaseExtraFeeRuleAmount($baseExtraFeeAmount);
            $appliedRuleIds[$rule->getRuleId()] = $rule->getRuleId();
            $this->_maintainAddressCouponCode($address, $rule);
            $this->_addDiscountDescription($address, $rule);
            if ($rule->getStopRulesProcessing()) {
                $this->_stopFurtherRules = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        $item->setAppliedRuleIds(join(',',$appliedRuleIds));
        $address->setAppliedRuleIds($this->mergeIds($address->getAppliedRuleIds(), $appliedRuleIds));
        $quote->setAppliedRuleIds($this->mergeIds($quote->getAppliedRuleIds(), $appliedRuleIds));
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _addDiscountDescription($address, $rule)
    {
        $description = $address->getExtraFeeRuleDescriptionArray();
        $ruleLabel = $rule->getStoreLabel($address->getQuote()->getStore());
        $label = '';
        if ($ruleLabel) {
            $label = $ruleLabel;
        } else if (strlen($address->getCouponCode())) {
            $label = $address->getCouponCode();
        }
        if (strlen($label)) {
            $description[$rule->getId()] = $label;
        }
        $address->setExtraFeeRuleDescriptionArray($description);
        return $this;
    }

    public function prepareDescription($address, $separator = ', ')
    {
        $descriptionArray = $address->getExtraFeeRuleDescriptionArray();
        if (!$descriptionArray && $address->getQuote()->getItemVirtualQty() > 0) {
            $descriptionArray = $address->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getExtraFeeRuleDescriptionArray();
        }
        $description = $descriptionArray && is_array($descriptionArray)
            ? implode($separator, array_unique($descriptionArray))
            :  '';
        $address->setExtraFeeRuleDescription($description);
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _isRuleApplicableForItem($rule, $item)
    {
        $address = $this->_getAddress($item);
        if (!$this->_canProcessRule($rule, $address)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!$rule->getActions()->validate($item)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected function _canProcessRule($rule, $address)
    {
        if ($rule->getExtraFeeAmount() == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return parent::_canProcessRule($rule, $address);
    }
}
```

> Step 8: app/code/local/Stack/ExtraFee/Model/SalesRule/Discount/Validator.php

```
<?php
class Stack_ExtraFee_Model_SalesRule_Discount_Validator extends Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator
{
    protected function _canProcessRule($rule, $address)
    {
        if (!Mage::helper('stack_extrafee')->isRuleExtraFeeEnabled()) {
            return parent::_canProcessRule($rule, $address);
        }
        if ($rule->getDiscountAmount() == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return parent::_canProcessRule($rule, $address);
    }
}
```

> Step 9: app/code/local/Stack/ExtraFee/Model/Sales/Order/Invoice/Total/Fee/Rule.php

```
<?php
class Stack_ExtraFee_Model_Sales_Order_Invoice_Total_Fee_Rule extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice_Total_Abstract
{
    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice $invoice)
    {
        if (!Mage::helper('stack_extrafee')->isRuleExtraFeeEnabled()) {
            return $this;
        }
        $invoice->setExtraFeeRuleAmount(0);
        $invoice->setBaseExtraFeeRuleAmount(0);
        if ($this->_isAmountInvoiced($invoice)) {
            return $this;
        }
        $extraFeeRuleAmount     = $invoice->getOrder()->getExtraFeeRuleAmount();
        $baseExtraFeeRuleAmount = $invoice->getOrder()->getBaseExtraFeeRuleAmount();
        if ($extraFeeRuleAmount) {
            $invoice->setExtraFeeRuleAmount($extraFeeRuleAmount);
            $invoice->setBaseExtraFeeRuleAmount($baseExtraFeeRuleAmount);
            $invoice->setGrandTotal($invoice->getGrandTotal() + $extraFeeRuleAmount);
            $invoice->setBaseGrandTotal($invoice->getBaseGrandTotal() + $baseExtraFeeRuleAmount);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _isAmountInvoiced($invoice)
    {
        foreach ($invoice->getOrder()->getInvoiceCollection() as $previusInvoice) {
            if ($previusInvoice->getExtraFeeRule() && !$previusInvoice->isCanceled()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

> Step 10: app/code/local/Stack/ExtraFee/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Fee/Rule.php

```
<?php
class Stack_ExtraFee_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Fee_Rule extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
{
    protected $_calculator;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_calculator = Mage::getSingleton('stack_extrafee/salesRule_validator');
    }

    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        if (!Mage::helper('stack_extrafee')->isRuleExtraFeeEnabled()) {
            return $this;
        }
        parent::collect($address);
        $quote = $address->getQuote();
        $store = Mage::app()->getStore($quote->getStoreId());
        $this->_calculator->reset($address);
        $items = $this->_getAddressItems($address);
        if (!count($items)) {
            return $this;
        }
        $this->_calculator->init($store->getWebsiteId(), $quote->getCustomerGroupId(), $quote->getCouponCode());
        $this->_calculator->initTotals($items, $address);
        $items = $this->_calculator->sortItemsByPriority($items);
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item->getParentItemId()) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isChildrenCalculated()) {
                foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                    $this->_calculator->process($child);
                    $this->_addAmount($child->getExtraFeeRuleAmount());
                    $this->_addBaseAmount($child->getBaseExtraFeeRuleAmount());
                }
            } else {
                $this->_calculator->process($item);
                $this->_addAmount($item->getExtraFeeRuleAmount());
                $this->_addBaseAmount($item->getBaseExtraFeeRuleAmount());
            }
        }
        $this->_calculator->prepareDescription($address);
    }

    public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        if (!Mage::helper('stack_extrafee')->isRuleExtraFeeEnabled()) {
            return $this;
        }
        $amount = $address->getExtraFeeRuleAmount();
        if ($address->getExtraFeeRuleDescription()) {
            $discountLabel = Mage::helper('stack_extrafee')->__('%s (%s)',
                Mage::helper('stack_extrafee')->getExtraFeeRuleLabel(), $address->getExtraFeeRuleDescription());
        } else {
            $discountLabel = Mage::helper('stack_extrafee')->getExtraFeeRuleLabel();
        }
        if ($amount > 0) {
            $address->addTotal(array(
                'code'  => $this->getCode(),
                'title' => $discountLabel,
                'value' => $amount
            ));
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

> Step 11: app/code/local/Stack/ExtraFee/Block/Sales/Order/Totals/Rule.php:

```
<?php
class Stack_ExtraFee_Block_Sales_Order_Totals_Rule extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{
    public function getSource()
    {
        return $this->getParentBlock()->getSource();
    }

    public function initTotals()
    {
        if ((float) $this->getSource()->getExtraFeeRuleAmount() <= 0) {
            return $this;
        }
        if ($this->getSource()->getExtraFeeRuleDescription()) {
            $discountLabel = $this->__('%s (%s)', Mage::helper('stack_extrafee')->getExtraFeeRuleLabel(),
                $this->getSource()->getExtraFeeRuleDescription());
        } else {
            $discountLabel = Mage::helper('stack_extrafee')->getExtraFeeRuleLabel();
        }
        $total = new Varien_Object(array(
            'code'  => 'extra_fee_rule',
            'field' => 'extra_fee_rule_amount',
            'value' => $this->getSource()->getExtraFeeRuleAmount(),
            'label' => $discountLabel
        ));
        $this->getParentBlock()->addTotalBefore($total, 'grand_total');
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: More steps can not be added because of limited characters.

Comment: Hi Mohit Kumar Arora,
Thank you so much for this. Is it a kind of extension?
I think i have installed this in my magento admin panel. But in the promotions menu when i try to add the Extra charges the field is not getting saved.

Comment: Ok @Praveen, I will check it in my localhost when I reach home and will share the complete module with you.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora I am using https://github.com/yvoronoy/magento-extension-extra-fee Everything working fine, I need to add small feature, how to set extra fees on order grant total permanently, if i go to check order in back-end the extra fees not available https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPfap.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use this free module

> https://github.com/PHOENIX-MEDIA/Magento-CashOnDelivery

I'm using it for both cash on delivery and card swipe on delivery.

I have implemented this on my website and it works perfect.